# Passing parameters to a javascript callback function

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to work out how to pass additional parameters to a javascript callback function.

In similar posts users have succeeded using anonymous function (these are new to me so I may have been doing them wrong) but I just can't get them to fire.

The below is what I have now, I need to be able to pass the itemId to the function "ajaxCheck_Callback" as well as the response.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks for the help.

```
function delete(itemId)
{
  selectpage.ajaxCheck(itemId, ajaxCheck_Callback);
}


Function ajaxCheck_Callback(response)

{
  alert(response);
  alert(itemId);
}
```

Thanks for the help guys. I now get undefined on my alert whereas previously this was alerting correctly.

```
function delete(itemId)
{
  selectpage.ajaxCheck(itemid, function () {ajaxCheck_Callback(itemid); });
}


function ajaxCheck_Callback(response)

{
  alert(response);
  alert(itemId);
}
```

Comment: What is `selectpage.ajaxCheck`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way is usually done is to use an anonymous function.

```
function deleteItem(itemId) {
    selectpage.ajaxCheck(itemId, function() { ajaxcheck_Callback(itemId); });
}

function ajaxCheck_Callback(response)
{
    alert(response);
}
```

Careful with your syntax, there are some errors in there. The `function` keyword has a lower-case `f` and you can't have a function named `delete`, that's a reserved keyword.

Comment: Good point about not using `delete` as a function name. (+1)

Comment: Thanks for this. This is what I was trying before but doesn't seem to work. What I posted originally gives a successful alert for response. When I add in the anonymous function I then get an undefined alert for response.

Comment: Please post your exact code (if possible, reproduce the problem in http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Thanks. I have updated original question with current code.

Comment: @JIbber4568 rename your function `delete` to something else.

Comment: @Xeon06 Sorry, I have already renamed it to "ItemDelete" just didn't copy it into the new code. ;-)

Comment: @JIbber4568 well everything seems in order. Maybe it has to do with your `ajaxCheck` function. Without a full example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) there's no way of telling what's wrong.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Was a bit strange that the response came through before but then not with the anon function. I've never used jsFiddle but will take a look and see if I can get something setup on there. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Create an anonymous function, which calls your callback, and supplies the needed parameter.

```
function deleteItemById(itemId)
{
  selectpage.ajaxCheck(itemId, function() { ajaxCheck_Callback(itemId); });
}
```

The anonymous function will create a closure over `itemId`, and therefore will still have access to this value even after the original call to delete has long since ended.

For completeness, also note that `delete` is a reserved word in JavaScript; you need to name this function something else.

Answer (score 3):

As your question mentions, you can do it using an anonymous function:

```
function deleteItem(itemId)
{
  selectpage.ajaxCheck(itemId, function ()
  {
      ajaxCheck_Callback(itemId);
  });
}

// Note, lowercase 'f' in 'function'
function ajaxCheck_Callback(response)
{
  alert(response);
}
```

It can also be done using a named function, which you might find more readable:

```
function deleteItem(itemId)
{
    function onAjaxCheck()
    {
        ajaxCheck_Callback(itemId);
    }

  selectpage.ajaxCheck(itemId, onAjaxCheck);
}
```

---

**N.B.** [as @Xeon06 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8359090/139010), [`delete` is a reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words), so that is not a valid function name.